# How do I subscribe to and update individual properties deeply nested inside a BehaviorSubject?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to create a way to dynamically build a data store of observables that can be individually subscribed to.  I'm using `BehaviorSubject` because the values of the generated data are subject to change and need to be reflected.

I'm creating a module for generating `SVG` code from data objects shaped like the interface below.

```
export interface GraphicElement{
    element: string;
    elementId: string;
    selfClosing?: boolean;
    bind?: GraphicBinding; //this property is most relevant to this question
    value?: string;
    properties: GraphicProperties;
    responsiveProperties?: ResponsiveProperties;
}

export interface GraphicBinding{
    library: string;
    property: string;
}
```

In my module I have an `svg-shell-component` that encapsulates all the code, an `svg-group-component` that iterates the `GraphicElement` objects into an `svg-element-component` which generates the svg element and injects it into the template.

The optional `bind` property will be what lets the component know a value will need to be bound to that element.  To give a real world example to better illustrate what I'm doing, I have a `product-spec-component` which shows diagrams of a product with measurements of the different dimensions, part sizes, open/closed span, etc. depending on the product.  The `product-data` which is a separate store from the `graphic-data` contains all the measurements for the different dimensions which will be what's used to generate the data that should be bound to in the instances of `svg-element-component` that displays a measurement.  The user will also be able to toggle between inches and centimeters which will be updating the value of the properties being bound to in this example.

My approach for handling this situation is to use a service file for dynamically generating and setting these properties in the shape of the following interface.

```
export interface GraphicBindingData{ [library: string] : GraphicBindingProperty; }
export interface GraphicBindingProperty{ [property:string] : string; }
```

So in this example there will be an object generated in the service file something like this

```
BindingData: GraphicBindingData = {
     specMeasurements:{
        width: '2in',
        height: '5in',
        thickness: '.125in',
        depth: '9in'
    },
    someOtherLibrary:{
        somePropA: 'some value',
        somePropB: 'some value'
    }
}
```

Going back to the `GraphicBinding` interface for the `bind` property in the `GraphicElement` interface, the `library` property will be set to `specMeasurements` and the `property` property would be set to the name of whichever dimension it needs to bind to.

So the `binding-data-service` file as we'll call it will be imported into the `product-spec-component` to set this data, while the `graphic-element-component` will use the values in the `bind` property to subscribe to whichever property it needs.  I added another object of dummy data because I want to show how it may be possible for there to be other objects of properties present to highlight even further what's making it difficult for me to figure out how to go about applying `BehaviorSubject` to the situation so an individual library or possibly and individual property in just one library may change while everything else remains the same.  In this example with the `product-spec-component` it's not much of an issue but in other aspects of how this module will be used there may be even more objects with possibly deeper levels of data.

I was thinking to do something like below.

```
export interface GraphicBindingData{ [library:string] : BehaviorSubject<GraphicBindingProperty>; }
export interface GraphicBindingProperty{ [property:string] : BehaviorSubject<string>; }
```

After considering how a `BehaviorSubject` is usually observed by another variable which is then subscribed to, I'm not sure of how to create an observer for each property in each library. I'm also not sure about how `.next()` will have to be used in such an instance to update the data.  I've been trying to find more info on using BehaviorSubjects within BehaviorSubjects and if that's even a thing that's necessary to do for what I want to achieve but haven't been able to find anything.  Can someone help me get a grasp on how to shape this so I can subscribe to and update the individual properties without effecting the other observables?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend nesting behavior subject, it'll make your stream consumption much more complex, it is probably better to use one single state object and apply some filtering logic

let say you have a object like

```
const myObj=new BehaviorSubject({orange:{apple:{cherry:'my cherry'},banana:'my banana'})
```

and you want to update cherry (it could be a pain to reconstruct immutable object here)

```
myObj.next({orange:{apple:{cherry:'my cherry updated'},banana:'my banana'})
```

and watch for cherry change

```
myObj.pipe(pluck('orange','apple','cherry'), distinctUntilChanged())
```

Because you have to .next() the entire object whenever one of the value changes, so to do that you have to destruct and re construct state object

```
const obj=myObj.value
//add a grape
myObj.next({...obj ,orange:{...obj.orange, grape:'my grape'}})

// or json stringify then json parse
const obj=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObj.value))
obj.orange.grape='my grape'
myObj.next(obj)
```

alternatively, you can just set the property directly if you don't want immutability

```
let obj=myObj.value
obj.orange.grape='my grape'
myObj.next(obj)
```

Comment: Smooth solution

Comment: hmmmm.  ok now what if I have something like `orange:{apple:{cherry: 'my cherry', grape: 'my grape'}}`?  Would I be able to change cherry without effecting grape?  I would think `.next()` in this instance would eliminate grape.  But then I could store the whole object in a variable inside the function and re-write cherry there and reset it with the same grape value.

Comment: yes as you said you can store the whole object in a variable without observable, but you just lose the reactivity, you have no way to know value changes as an event. next() is to make the value change explicit for other function to subscribe()

Answer (score 0):

What about state manegement

You've to use NgRx to make use for all your state changes for this tree of porperties

Answer (score 0):

Ok I wound up figuring out a way to achieve this.  I had to re-shape my interfaces like this

```
export interface BindingObject{ [library:string] : BindingItem; }
export interface BindingItem{ [property:string] : BehaviorSubject<string>; }

export interface BindingObjectObservable{ [library:string] : BindingItemObservable; }
export interface BindingItemObservable{ [property:string] : Observable<string>; }
```

So instead of having one solid object as a `BehaviorSubject` and another as an `Observable` I just made it to where each property is a `BehaviorSubject` which is then observed and subscribed to individually and can be updated without effecting the other properties in the library.